# How exactly to get the fitted values after applying the dynamic factor model using the statsmodels package?

Tags: python, dataframe, statsmodels

I want to obtain the fitted values from this model, but I'm unable to figure out how to do that.

I've tried using the dynamic factor model under the `statsmodels` package, but during using the `predict` function on my model, it is asking for 'params' argument where I am not getting what to put.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

endog= df.loc[0:,'BSE':'SS.Shanghai']
dfm = sm.tsa.DynamicFactor(endog,k_factors=1,factor_order=2,error_order=2)

r1 = dfm.fit(method = 'powell',cov_type='robust',disp=False)
dy_fit = dfm.fit(r1.params,cov_type='opg',disp=False)

dfm.predict()
```

Here `df` is a data frame containing time series data of returns from various stock indices.

This is the error I'm Getting while putting any parameters in the `dfm.predict` function:

```
205         This is a placeholder intended to be overwritten by individual models.
207         raise NotImplementedError

NotImplementedError:
```

Answer (score 0):

The `predict` method is only available from the fitted results. So you would use e.g. `dy_fit.predict()`.